# Brand Azure AD B2C emails

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Does anyone know if there's a way to brand the emails sent by Azure AD B2C?

This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization says the features use company branding instead of specific B2C branding, but this doesn't seem to have any options for the emails just sign in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level of branding looks quite limited, see the below [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#how-do-i-customize-verification-emails--the-content-and-the--from---field--sent-by-azure-ad-b2c-):

Azure B2C emails inherit the logo and company name set in custom branding, no way to change the from field.

Comment: Any idea for certain what field should set the logo on the email? I tried setting all the images and the colour, but the verification email still sent with no logo and a blue background.

Should this have actually done it and it was taking a while to update?

Comment: I believe it picks up the [banner logo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding), I would give it some time to update

Answer (score 1):

There is some movement, you can now send mails through an external mail service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email

This provides a lot of options for customization.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by James, they are not very customizable.

Please see [this UserVoice item request the B2C to improve this.](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334335-fully-customizable-verification-emails)